# How to get Youtube actual http source address

Tags: hyperlink

I'am an engineer to develop OTT box use Youtube XML interface, I get a problem that the http source in the XML is not a real one, I only could use tool to convert it to actual flv source.

I wonder is there any theory or source code to get the actual flv source address, NOT the tools.

thank u very much!

Comment: Have you gotten in touch with YouTube about setting up this interface? You will need their authorization to set this up, long-term, and once you have done so, you can discuss the interface with them.